# Solving short ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What type of ODE is this and how to solve it analytically?

$\dot{v} = c \cdot v^2 $

where

$v = v(t)$, $\dot{v} = \frac{dv(t)}{dt}$ and $c = \text{const}$.

Comment: It is a non-linear ODE where the variables can be separated. The solution is therefore given by an integraton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{dv}{dt}=cv^2$$
$$\int\frac{dv}{v^2}=\int cdt$$
$$-\frac{1}{v}=ct + C$$

It's a linear ODE (not sure about the classification though)

Comment: According to a popular online math engine: first-order nonlinear ordinary differential equation

Comment: "It's a linear ODE" Well, no, it is not that.